Filtering Craft Commerce products by all variant prices with pagination
I'm working with Craft Commerce 5 and need to filter products based on the prices of all their variants while also using pagination.
Requirements:

Filter products by the prices of all their variants (e.g., between 100€ and 500€).
Use pagination to display the results.

Attempts and Issues:

Using defaultPrice with Pagination:

{% set minPrice = 100 %}
{% set maxPrice = 500 %}
{% set orderBy = 'dateCreated desc' %}

{% set productsQuery = craft.commerce.products()
    .defaultPrice(['and', '>= ' ~ minPrice, '<= ' ~ maxPrice])
    .orderBy(orderBy)
%}

{% paginate productsQuery.limit(12) as pageInfo, pageProducts %}

{% for product in pageProducts %}
    <h2>{{ product.title }}</h2>
    {% for variant in product.variants %}
        <p>Variant: {{ variant.title }}</p>
        <p>Price: {{ variant.price }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}

Issue: defaultPrice only considers the default variant price, not the prices of all variants. It returns results only when the price range starts from 0. This method does not account for a comprehensive price range from all variants within a product. Documentation Reference

Filtering Variants in Loop (Resource-Intensive and Pagination Issues):

{% set minPrice = 100 %}
{% set maxPrice = 500 %}

{% set products = craft.commerce.products().all() %}

{% set filteredProducts = [] %}

{% for product in products %}
    {% set validVariants = product.variants
        |filter(variant => variant.price >= minPrice and variant.price <= maxPrice)
    %}
    {% if validVariants|length %}
        {% set product = product|merge({ validVariants: validVariants }) %}
        {% set filteredProducts = filteredProducts|merge([product]) %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{% for product in filteredProducts %}
    <h2>{{ product.title }}</h2>
    {% for variant in product.validVariants %}
        <p>Variant: {{ variant.title }}</p>
        <p>Price: {{ variant.price }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}

Issue: This approach is resource-intensive and does not work well with pagination. For as much as this solution is functional (remains to be verified), it is not efficient.
Question:
How can I efficiently filter products by the prices of all their variants (considering all variants, not just the default variant) while supporting pagination in Twig?
